# Why would this line of code be executed if the IF condition is false? Doesn't make any sense

Tags: php, if-statement

Here's the code:

```
<?php



class Order extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
 {
 protected $_name = 'orders';

 protected $_limit = 200;

 protected $_authorised = false;

 public function setLimit($limit)
 {
 $this->_limit = $limit;
 }

 public function setAuthorised($auth)
 {
 $this->_authorised = (bool) $auth;
 }

 public function insert(array $data)
 {
     if ($data['amount'] > $this->_limit && $this->_authorised === false) {
         throw new Exception('Unauthorised transaction of greater than ' . this->_limit . ' units');
     }
     return parent::insert($data);
 }
 }
```

Why would that method run **ONLY** if the condition fails. I'm a C# programmer, I my logic dictates that it will run regardless of the IF, correct? Thanks a million.

Comment: Is `$this->_authorised === false` allowed in PHP?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php , it is allowed. It is the equivalence operator.

Comment: $Gentlemen: Using the triple equals sign compares both value AND data type.

Comment: Could you please clarify which method you are talking about and provide the output of the two conditions in the `if` statement? :-)

Comment: I pulled the code from this site: http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/the.model I'm learning Zend.

Comment: Languages have advanced, so I'm getting too old to catch up...Sorry Sergio.

So, what if there is not value in `$data['amount'] `? What does that return?

Comment: If it returns  `false` whole statements false.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that either `false > $this->_limit` or `$data['amount'] > $this->_limit == false`?

Comment: I didnt read your comment well enough, if `$data[amount]` does not have a value, the expression `$data[amount] > 200` will return `false`, therefore whole expression is false.

Comment: Ok, if exception is thrown, where is it handled? I don't see exception caught or passed on like on Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you throw an exception, that usually causes the remaining code to exit unless you have a `try...catch` statement. Thus, if the amount is greater than 200 and the user is not authorized, it will execute the block inside of the `if` statement.

The link you provided mentions that it will "bubble up" to a controller where it ***will*** be caught. Since it's not caught in your code above (the model), execution inside of the model stops and is passed up the stack to the controller. It does not return to your model, thus the line following the `if` will not be called.

Check out the [PHP manual on exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Exception will interrupt code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Even in C# if an exception is thrown code beyond it doesn't get executed.